Topological counterexample for M(K, Y1 × Z1) being a subbasis of the compact open topology of C(X,Y×Z)
We are trying to answer whether the following mapping is continuous and open
$$C(X, Y \times Z) \to C(X, Y ) \times C(X, Z)$$ (the topological spaces being provided with the compact-open topology). We are sure that the mapping is continuous but we assume that it is not open. If within X any compact subset of X is locally compact like given in Hausdorff spaces the sets that look like $M(K, X_1 \times X_2)$; $X_1$, $X_2$ being open in $X$ or $Y$ form a subbasis of the compact open topology of $C(X, Y \times Z)$ so the mapping will be open. Sadly not any space in which compact subsets are not locally compact like for example the Alexandroff compactification of the rational numbers will work out as a counterexample for $X$. If you come up with any possible room $X$ where the sets of the mentioned type do not form a subbasis I would be very thankful if you could notify me.
Thank you!!!

We already found out that the room X must furfill the following critera

X should be comapct (it doesnt matter weather K ist X or a subset)
X must be the union set of several open sets
Among any finit number of compact sets whose union set equals X there must must be one that is not a subset of either one of the open sets that cover X from 2).


'room' = Raum? In English it would be 'space', just so you know for future.

May I ask what's the source/motivation for this question?

yes room = Raum. I am currently studying math at the university in Bochum. This question was asked in our topology lecture. I tried to find an answer for about 3 weeks on my own without success and also asked  my teachers. It turned out that they made a mistake in their solutions or did not know one. This question is from Laures and Szymiks book Grundkurs Topologie. But Laures and Szymik do not have a solution neather. So one of my teachers suggested that I might find someone able to help here.
